# Google Spreadsheets if == '' not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a spreadsheet that loops over the values in two columns. One column (47) contains the message that will be sent in the email and the other column (48) contains a time stamp of when the message was sent.

The script checks if the message value is not empty and if the time stamp is empty.  If so, this means the message was never sent and then the script sends the message.

I want it to not send the message if there is a value in the time stamp column.  I've used this before and it has worked in the past, I'm not sure why it's not working now.  Even though there is a time stamp, it still sends the message.  What am I missing?  Here is the code (sorry, it's not the best written code, I know. Any tips to make it better would be appreciated):

```
function listingPending2WeekNoticeEmail() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("VacancyReportMarketing");

  // figure out what the last row is
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  // the rows are indexed starting at 1, and the first 3 row
  // is the headers, so start with row 4
  var startRow = 4;

  // grab the '2 week notice sent' column 48 (AV)) 
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,48,lastRow-startRow+1,1 );
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var timestamp_values = range.getValues();

  // Now, grab the listing pending 2 week notice column 47 (AU) 
  range = sheet.getRange(4, 47, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
  numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var reminder_info_values = range.getValues();

  var warning_count = 0;
  var msg = "";

  // Loop over the days left values
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var timestamp = timestamp_values[i][0];
    var reminder_info = reminder_info_values[i][0];
    //    var days_left = days_left_values[i][0];
    if(reminder_info != '' && timestamp == '') {
      Logger.log(timestamp);
      // if reminder not empty but timestamp empty, do something with the data.

      var reminder_name = reminder_info_values[i][0];

      msg = msg + reminder_name+"\n\n";
      var msg2 = "\n"+"Within the 2 weeks prior to unit being estimated ready, Marketing Department should begin advertising the above units. If assets are missing, Marketing should begin scheduling with the property manager a time to visit the property as soon as it is ready. Please begin to compile your schedule to collect missing assets and submit to Marketing Manager for approval. Thank you!"
      warning_count++;


    }
  }

  if(warning_count) {
    MailApp.sendEmail("example@gmail.com,example@yahoo.com", 
                      "2 WEEK NOTICE - LISTINGS PENDING", msg+msg2);
    timestamp2WeekNoticeSent();

  }

};

function timestamp2WeekNoticeSent(){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("VacancyReportMarketing");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()

  for (var i = 1; i <= lastRow; i++){
    // get column AU (47), every row to last row
    var noticeRange = sheet.getRange([i], 47);
    var noticeValues = noticeRange.getValues();
    // get column AV (48), every row to last row
    var timeRange = sheet.getRange([i], 48);
    var timeValues = timeRange.getValues();

    if (noticeValues != '' && timeValues == ''){ // 
      timeRange.setValue(new Date());

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The variable that determines whether email is sent is `warning_count`. So start by logging, `Logger.log(warning_count)` in that loop to see why it becomes positive.

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that I'm getting the range of column 48 starting with row 2 when my start row should be 4. I'm getting the range of column 47 starting with 4 like I should.  Because of the mismatch, when I loop over the values, they aren't being looped over in the same row.  So I simply changed the getRange value of column 48 to start with 4 instead of 2 and it's now working.  Ugh...